# searching users from facebook, with their name and other attributes

Tags: facebook, search, profiles

I want to create a search engine for Facebook. It should search users on social networking site Facebook. So can I use Graph API for the purpose ?? or is there any other technology available which I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the Graph API for this. see the "Search" Section of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

> You can search over all public objects
>   in the social graph with
>   https://graph.facebook.com/search

Comment: yes I have taken look into it, but when I try to search with type=user it gives error for Oauth that you do not have valid access token. I think when a user logs into the Facebook account he gets an access token and that helps him do various stuff in their facebook account like search and all. so in my case also I have to have a valid facebook account for using this graph API's search functionality ? I am making a search engine :(. I think I have progressed enough in this direction by searching with access token of a dummy account with this API. any other way ?

Comment: try it with an application token. see reference/api

Comment: you can't search for all users, you can only serarch for users who are friend of a user. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dmark%26type%3Duser